# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `comment_cflags_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f423040d570>:0x007f42300dd170>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a very basic Photo and Comment model that works and then I have a built a Cflag model that is used to flag comments. I am getting the following error from Heroku log when I visit the photos/show.html.erb view:

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `comment_cflags_path'
>   for #<#:0x007f42300dd170>

**Show:**

```
photos/show.html.erb
.
<% @photo.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= form_for([comment, Cflag.new]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
    <%= f.submit "Report Inappropiate" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Routes:**

```
resources :photos do
  resources :comments do
    resources :cflags
  end
end
```

**Rails routes:**

```
    photo_comment_cflags GET        /photos/:photo_id/comments/:comment_id/cflags(.:format)          cflags#index
                         POST       /photos/:photo_id/comments/:comment_id/cflags(.:format)          cflags#create
 new_photo_comment_cflag GET        /photos/:photo_id/comments/:comment_id/cflags/new(.:format)      cflags#new
edit_photo_comment_cflag GET        /photos/:photo_id/comments/:comment_id/cflags/:id/edit(.:format) cflags#edit
     photo_comment_cflag GET        /photos/:photo_id/comments/:comment_id/cflags/:id(.:format)      cflags#show
                         PATCH      /photos/:photo_id/comments/:comment_id/cflags/:id(.:format)      cflags#update
                         PUT        /photos/:photo_id/comments/:comment_id/cflags/:id(.:format)      cflags#update
                         DELETE     /photos/:photo_id/comments/:comment_id/cflags/:id(.:format)      cflags#destroy
PhotosController
def show
  @photo = Photo.approved.find(params[:id])
end
```

**Photo Controller:**

```
def create
   @photo = Photo.find(params[:photo_id])
   @comment = @photo.comments.build(comment_params)
   @comment.save
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to :back }
     format.js 
   end 
end
```

**Cflag Model:**

```
class Cflag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :comment, counter_cache: true
  belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true 
  validates :comment_id, presence: true
  validates :user_id, uniqueness: { 
    scope: [:comment_id],
    message: 'You can only flag a comment once. Thank you for your feedback.'
  }
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
end
```

**Cflags controller:**

```
class CflagsController < ApplicationController
before_action :logged_in_user

def new
end

def create
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:comment_id])
  @cflag = @comment.cflags.build(cflag_params)
    if @cflag.save
      if @comment.cflags_count > 1
        @comment.update_attribute(:approved, false)  
        flash[:success] = "Flag created! Comment ##{@comment.id} has been removed for review. Thank you for your feedback"
        redirect_to :back
      else    
        flash[:success] = "Flag created! Thank you for your feedback"
        redirect_to :back
      end
    else
      redirect_to :back, notice: @cflag.errors.full_messages  
    end    
  end    

  private 
    def cflag_params
      params.require(:cflag).permit(:user_id, :comment_id).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
    end
end
```

**Schema:**

```
create_table "cflags", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "comment_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

add_index "cflags", ["comment_id"], name: "index_cflags_on_comment_id"
add_index "cflags", ["user_id"], name: "index_cflags_on_user_id"
```

I changed the form to:

```
<% @photo.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= form_for([comment, url: photo_comment_cflags_path]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
    <%= f.submit "Report Inappropiate" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And got the following error from `Heroku:`

> ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"index",
>   :controller=>"cflags", :id=>"100"} missing required keys:
>   [:comment_id, :photo_id]):

Comment: You need to pass photo and comment id in the path, `form_for([comment, url: photo_comment_cflags_path(@photo, comment)])`.

Comment: I get the following error with this code: **ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for {:url=>"/photos/98/comments/306/cflags"}:Hash):**

Comment: I've decided to start a new topic as this topic answers the initial question. that topic is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549031/actionviewtemplateerror-undefined-method-model-name-for-url-photos-1

Comment: @Sahil i still wasnt able to figure it out  so i am offering a bounty on it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549031/edited-actionviewtemplateerror-no-route-matches-missing-required-keys

Comment: Will try solving it. I thought it was already solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your routes:

```
/photos/:photo_id/comments/:comment_id/cflags(.:format)
```

Your path need also a `photo_id`.

You are missing the `@photo` in your `form_for`. Just change the `form_for` to:

```
<%= form_for([@photo, comment, Cflag.new]) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not find this in Rails guide under Form Helpers - did I miss it or is there somewhere else it is covered?

Comment: You can find an example in the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) about resources with defined associations.

Comment: Ok, I got a chance to check this now and it does not work. The error I get from Heroku is: `ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"index", :comment_id=>nil, :controller=>"cflags", :photo_id=>"98"} missing required keys: [:comment_id]):`  I then changed the code to `[@photo, comment.id, Cflag.new]` and I got the following error from Heroku: `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `to_model' for 304:Fixnum` ... In Heroku Console... `p=Photo.find(100) -> p.comments -> => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Comment id: 304`

Comment: I've decided to start a new topic as this topic answers the initial question. that topic is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549031/actionviewtemplateerror-undefined-method-model-name-for-url-photos-1

Comment: i still wasn't able to figure this out so I am offering a bounty on it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549031/edited-actionviewtemplateerror-no-route-matches-missing-required-keys