# Edited... ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches... missing required keys: [:comment_id])

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the following error from Heroku log when I visit the `photos/show.html.erb` view:

> ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"index", :comment_id=>nil, :controller=>"cflags", :photo_id=>"100"} missing required keys: [:comment_id])

I have very basic `Photo` and `Comment` models that work correctly and then I have built a `Cflag` model that is used to flag comments. I use `@photo.comments` to list the comments in the `photos/show.html.erb` view.

**Show:**

```
# photos/show.html.erb

<% @photo.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= form_for(comment, url: photo_comment_cflags_path(@photo, comment)) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
    <%= f.submit "Report Inappropiate" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Cflags Controller:**

```
class CflagsController < ApplicationController
before_action :logged_in_user

def new
end

def create
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:comment_id])
  @cflag = @comment.cflags.build(cflag_params)
    if @cflag.save
      if @comment.cflags_count > 1
        @comment.update_attribute(:approved, false)  
        flash[:success] = "Flag created! Comment ##{@comment.id} has been removed for review. Thank you for your feedback"
        redirect_to :back
      else    
        flash[:success] = "Flag created! Thank you for your feedback"
        redirect_to :back
      end
    else
      redirect_to :back, notice: @cflag.errors.full_messages  
    end    
  end    

  private 
    def cflag_params
      params.require(:cflag).permit(:user_id, :comment_id).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
    end
end
```

**Routes:**

```
resources :photos do
  resources :comments, only: [:create, :edit, :destroy] do
    resources :cflags, only: :create
  end  
end
```

**Rails routes:**

```
    photo_comment_cflags GET        /photos/:photo_id/comments/:comment_id/cflags(.:format)          cflags#index
                         POST       /photos/:photo_id/comments/:comment_id/cflags(.:format)          cflags#create
 new_photo_comment_cflag GET        /photos/:photo_id/comments/:comment_id/cflags/new(.:format)      cflags#new
edit_photo_comment_cflag GET        /photos/:photo_id/comments/:comment_id/cflags/:id/edit(.:format) cflags#edit
     photo_comment_cflag GET        /photos/:photo_id/comments/:comment_id/cflags/:id(.:format)      cflags#show
                         PATCH      /photos/:photo_id/comments/:comment_id/cflags/:id(.:format)      cflags#update
                         PUT        /photos/:photo_id/comments/:comment_id/cflags/:id(.:format)      cflags#update
                         DELETE     /photos/:photo_id/comments/:comment_id/cflags/:id(.:format)      cflags#destroy
```

**Photos Controller:**

```
def show
  @photo = Photo.approved.find(params[:id])
end
```

**Comments Controller:**

```
def create
   @photo = Photo.find(params[:photo_id])
   @comment = @photo.comments.build(comment_params)
   @comment.save
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to :back }
     format.js 
   end 
end
```

**Cflag Model:**

```
class Cflag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :comment, counter_cache: true
  belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true 
  validates :comment_id, presence: true
  validates :user_id, uniqueness: { 
    scope: [:comment_id],
    message: 'You can only flag a comment once. Thank you for your feedback.'
  }
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
end
```

**Schema:**

```
create_table "cflags", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "comment_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

add_index "cflags", ["comment_id"], name: "index_cflags_on_comment_id"
add_index "cflags", ["user_id"], name: "index_cflags_on_user_id"
```

**In Heroku Console**

```
p = Photo.find(100) 
p.comments = => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Comment id: 309, content: "hi", photo_id: 100, user_id: 1, created_at: "2016-07-24 04:43:17", updated_at: "2016-07-24 04:43:17", approved: true, cflags_count: nil>
```

Comment: Hi, what happens if a comment is already reported in the show page?

Comment: Well I have not yet gotten the page with the form to load but if it did load and a cflag already existed then it would trigger: `else
      redirect_to :back, notice: @cflag.errors.full_messages`  because of the uniqueness scope in the model: `validates :user_id, uniqueness: { 
    scope: [:comment_id],`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the form action to this, 
**Updated**:

```
<% if @photo.comments.any? %>
   <% @photo.comments.each do |comment| %>     
     # you do not have to use comment in form_for, because this form is for creating cflag
     <%= form_for(:cflag, url: photo_comment_cflags_path(@photo, comment), method: "post") do |f| %> 
          <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %> 
          <%= f.submit "Report Inappropiate" %> 
     <% end %> 
   <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Till now you were using the index action instead of the create action, as **photo_comment_cflags** stands for index action(notice the extra **s** changes the entire meaning).

Comment: I am getting the following error: `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method photo_comment_cflag_path`. However, changing it to `photo_comment_cflags_path` makes it work.  I have set the cflag route to `only: create`. It is amazing, because I tried Cflag.new and @cflag with the same code. I guess `:cflag` is literally the difference between the code working/not working.

Comment: Can you prepend `new_` to the url which is mentioned in my code?

Comment: Actually testing now and Cflag.new and :cflag both work. Going to continue testing to isolate what was the specific code that allows this to work. When I change the route to `new_photo_comment_cflag_path` I get the following error: `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `new_photo_comment_cflag_path'`

Comment: Can you please add :new method also in the routes, right now it just accepts :create.

Comment: The page loads but when I try to submit the cflag it ends up stuck on `example.com/photo/id/comment/id/cflag/new`. Do you not feel content with `url: photo_comment_cflags_path` ?

Comment: The url which you are saying is used for going to index action and not create. This can be solved by this also, url: "/photos/#{@photo.id}/comment/#{comment.id}/cflags", otherwise you can use the which you suggested: `photo_comment_flags_path` with `method: "post"`.

Comment: but in rake routes it says `/photos/:photo_id/comments/:comment_id/cflags(.:format)          cflags#create`? if we specify method: "post" this is still not ideal?

Comment: Sorry its comments, missed one s. Isn't the other one working "photo_comment_cflags_path"?

Comment: I guess the only missing thing was, `method: 'post'`, which creates the correct url.

Comment: the route that works is `photo_comment_cflags_path`, same as the OP.

Comment: yes, it also has to be `:cflag`, or `Cflag.new`. It can't be `comment`.

Comment: I guess still need `method: 'post'` even though the route is `only: :create`

Comment: Yes `post` will be needed other wise it gets translated to `get request` which takes you to index instead of `create` action.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Rails documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for), `form_for` method expected arguments are `(record, options = {}, &block)`.

> **form_for(record, options = {}, &block)** *public*
>
> Creates a form that allows the user to create or update the attributes
>   of a specific model object.
>
> The method can be used in several slightly different ways, depending
>   on how much you wish to rely on Rails to infer automatically from the
>   model how the form should be constructed. For a generic model object,
>   a form can be created by passing `form_for` a string or symbol
>   representing the object we are concerned with:

So you may want to remove the extra `[]` you inserted in the `form_for` method and it should look like this:

```
<% @photo.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= form_for(Cflag.new, url: photo_comment_cflags_path(@photo, comment)) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
    <%= f.submit "Report Inappropiate" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I suggest you to try it like this and see if it resolves your current issue.

Comment: I get the following error with this code `ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"index", :comment_id=>nil, :controller=>"cflags", :photo_id=>"100"} missing required keys: [:comment_id]):`

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss, I have updated my answer. From the form you need a new `Cflag` rather than a comment right?

Comment: I am still getting the same error: `ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"index", :comment_id=>nil, :controller=>"cflags", :photo_id=>"100"} missing required keys: [:comment_id]):`

Comment: it seems your request is still handled by the `index` action rather than the `create` action here. Though this is not required can you try enforcing the form method as `:post` and see if it resolves this issue?

`<%= form_for(Cflag.new, url: photo_comment_cflags_path(@photo, comment), html: {method: :post}) do |f| %>`

Comment: no, it is the same error message. I am so confused. The initial error message I got when I had the extra `[ ]` in the form_for shows the correct url in the error message -> `{:url=>"/photos/100/comments/309/cflags"}`

Answer (score 0):

Your first argument is array, try this:

```
<%= form_for(comment, url: photo_comment_cflags_path(@photo, comment)) do |f| %>
```

Comment: I get the following error with this code `ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"index", :comment_id=>nil, :controller=>"cflags", :photo_id=>"100"} missing required keys: [:comment_id]):`